# VHDL - Behavioral work correctly, Post Route has problem

Tags: vhdl, flip-flop

I'm new on StackOverflow and I'm sorry for eventual error. 
I'm workin on VHDL and I have a problem with the Post-Place & Route. While behavioral works correctly, Post-Place & Route has problem and the result remain UNDEFINED for the all the time.

```
entity step1 is
  port (   d: in std_logic_vector (0 to 5);
        clk : in std_logic;
            RESET: in std_logic;
        q: out std_logic_vector (0 to 5)
         );
end step1;

architecture Behavioral of step1 is

begin
  ff: process (clk)
  begin
      if (clk'event and clk='1') then
        if (RESET = '1') then
          q <= "000000";
          else
          q <= d;
          end if;
    end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I place here the code. It should be a flip flop D that I use to make a pipeline architecture. 
 Thanks for your reply, and please excuse me for any mistake.
Here's the test bench:

```
entity test_step1 is
end test_step1
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF test_step1 IS 

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

COMPONENT step1
PORT(
     input : IN  std_logic_vector(0 to 5);
     clk : IN  std_logic;
     RESET : IN  std_logic;
     output : OUT  std_logic_vector(0 to 5)
    );
END COMPONENT;
--Inputs
signal input : std_logic_vector(0 to 5) := (others => '0');
signal clk : std_logic := '0';
signal RESET : std_logic := '0';

--Outputs
signal output : std_logic_vector(0 to 5);

-- Clock period definitions
constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;
BEGIN

-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
uut: step1 PORT MAP (
      input => input,
      clk => clk,
      RESET => RESET,
      output => output
    );

 -- Clock process definitions
 clk_process :process
 begin
  clk <= '0';
  wait for clk_period/2;
  clk <= '1';
  wait for clk_period/2;
 end process;
 -- Stimulus process
 stim_proc: process 
 begin    
    -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
  RESET <= '1';
    wait for 10 ns;
  RESET <= '0';
  input <= "111111";
    wait for clk_period*10;
  input <= "101010";

  -- insert stimulus here 

  wait;
  end process;

 END;
```

Comment: The code is O.K., what is your testbench?

Comment: Ok thanks, I post to you the testbench too

Comment: Your testbench is missing a semicolon on "end test_step1" and the port name of step1 doesn't match (input vs d). Fixing that, post-route simulation works on my Vivado installation (2018.2). Make sure the testbench is only marked as "simulation" by right-clicking on the file and selecting "Set used-in". I suggest you rename "test_step1" to "step1_tb", which is standard and may be picked up as simulation sources by Vivado automatically.

Comment: The correction you suggest to me was already fixed, I've copied an old version. But on Xilinx doesn't work. I've two warning that I don't understand HDLCompiler 89 and 648

Comment: please, Give the warning message with the warning number to get better help and answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first warning messages for HDL Compiler 89 and 648 found on the internet are:

> WARNING:HDLCompiler:89 - "my_module" remains a black-box since it has no binding entity.
>
> WARNING:Simulator:648 - "Top_LCD_test.vhd" Line 35. Instance top_lcd is unboundCompiling architecture behavior of entity testbench

This means that the compiler has not fount any entity corresponding to the component used in your testbench.

In your case, **the port names of your entity and component didn't match !**

Try to use the same names in port for the component and entity :

```
entity test_step1 is
end test_step1;
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF test_step1 IS 

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

COMPONENT step1
PORT(
     d : IN  std_logic_vector(0 to 5);
     clk : IN  std_logic;
     RESET : IN  std_logic;
     q : OUT  std_logic_vector(0 to 5)
    );
END COMPONENT;
--Inputs
signal input : std_logic_vector(0 to 5) := (others => '0');
signal clk : std_logic := '0';
signal RESET : std_logic := '0';

--Outputs
signal output : std_logic_vector(0 to 5);

-- Clock period definitions
constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;
BEGIN

-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
uut: step1 PORT MAP (
      d => input,
      clk => clk,
      RESET => RESET,
      q => output
    );

 -- Clock process definitions
 clk_process :process
 begin
  clk <= '0';
  wait for clk_period/2;
  clk <= '1';
  wait for clk_period/2;
 end process;
 -- Stimulus process
 stim_proc: process 
 begin    
    -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
  RESET <= '1';
    wait for 10 ns;
  RESET <= '0';
  input <= "111111";
    wait for clk_period*10;
  input <= "101010";

  -- insert stimulus here 

  wait;
  end process;
```